# Connecting filezilla to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, filezilla

So I am trying to use Joomla! to design a website and I've been following the instructions. One of the requirements is to move the downloaded Joomla! package to the server (MySQL). They recommended Filezilla for the transfer but everytime I try to connect, I keep getting the errors below. I'm pretty sure the details I entered are correct for host, username, password and port number because it looks like it is about to connect and then I lose it. Anyone had this problem or know how to resolve it? Thanks. P.s I'm pretty new to web development.

```
      Status:   Connecting to [fe80::932:330c:e414:5c42%13]:3306...
      Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
      Response: D
      Error:    Could not connect to server
      Status:   Waiting to retry...
      Status:   Resolving address of Ikemesit-HP
      Status:   Connecting to [fe80::932:330c:e414:5c42%13]:3306...
      Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
      Response: D
      Error:    Connection closed by server
      Error:    Could not connect to server
```

Comment: This is probably best directed at your host's tech support dept. Are you using FTP or SFTP? In Filezilla there are several options for SFTP, too - check these with your host's recommended settings.

Comment: Why upload files to a MySQL server??? MySQL is a database server, you usually use SQL to communicate with it.

Comment: Is it a problem if the host is my computer? and yes I'm using FTP

Comment: I'm sure they mean use FTP to connect to your allocated web space, and use another tool such as `phpmyadmin`/`create database` in a CPanel to create the schema.

Comment: Have you tried some troubleshooting tips like: telnet to the destination address on the right port?

Comment: @ZombieHunter that's what the instructions said to do

Comment: Wait, is that a IPV6 Address I spy there?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to [check the instructions again](http://kb.greengeeks.com/1459/how-to-manually-install-joomla/), that doesn't sound right. You wouldn't use Filezilla to transfer files to a mySQL database as the two don't really work together. Filezilla is for moving files to/from a file server but database servers don't really work this way.

Once you have the Joomla files on your file server, you would just visit the URL for the website and enter the database credentials there. Not try to connect via FTP.

Comment: ohhhhh I've been confusing myself. Thanks @Liam. Sorry newbie. I'll let u know progress

Comment: Glad you found this helpful. If there's anything else please feel free to ask. But if this helped you close out your question please accept the answer so others that come across it will also know that this response was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

FileZilla is a FTP Client which lets you connect to an allocated space on the hosting companies HDD, which will contain your web scripts. Usually

`/public_html`

What they mean is:

1) Use Filezilla to upload the scripts to the allocated space

2) Use a MySQL tool, to create a database schema

3) navigate to yourwebsite.com/install

4) Follow installation instructions

5) Remove install directory

6) Run your website.